# How to vertically and horizontally align two divs beside each other

Tags: html, css

I have two divs that I want centred horizontally and vertically in the middle of the top of the page but trying various types of "vertically align" & "margin: auto 0" commands simply aren't working (for what I'm trying at least. Can anybody please shine some light on where I'm going wrong here please. Thank you in advance!

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">

  <div id="find-us" class="col-md-5">
    <h5 style="color:#205ba0; margin-bottom:0px; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px;">Our Office</h5>
    Our office is located in the heart of Seven Sisters; an up and coming area in North London. Seven Sisters has had a lot of improvement in recent years with the Central & European investments into the area.<br>
    Seven Sisters have an excellent transport links. Commuters have the options of Victoria line to West End or British rail to Liverpool Street.<br><br>

    <h5 style="color:#205ba0; margin-bottom:0px; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px;">Contact</h5>
    Telephone: 020 8211 0005<br>
    Email: enquiries@abbapropertyservices.co.uk<br>
    Address: ABBA Property Services, 88 West Green Road, London N15 5NS<br><br>

    <h5 style="color:#205ba0; margin-bottom:0px; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px;">Transport</h5>
    Tube/Train: Seven Sisters Underground Station, Seven Sisters Railway Station, South Tottenham Railway Station<br>
    Bus: 41, N41<br><br>

    <h5 style="color:#205ba0; margin-bottom:0px; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px;">Opening Hours</h5>
    Monday: 9am - 5pm<br>
    Tuesday: 9am - 5pm<br>
    Wednesay: 9am - 5pm<br>
    Thursday: 9am - 5pm<br>
    Friday: 9am - 5pm<br>
    Saturday: 10am - 1pm<br>
    Sunday: Closed<br>
  </div>

  <div id="find-photo" class="col-md-5">
    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2479.0948652696484!2d-0.07885818431106212!3d51.584824712860375!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x48761c1135485d4b%3A0x487d1b5ae3bd4621!2s88+W+Green+Rd%2C+London+N15+5NS!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suk!4v1491925605605" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
#find-us {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid pink;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.col-centered{
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#find-photo {
  height: 100%;
}
#contact-form {
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  margin-left: 30%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: read about flex box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;` on `.wrapper`

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
#find-us {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid pink;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.col-centered{
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#find-photo {
  height: 100%;
}
#contact-form {
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div id="find-us" class="col-md-5">
    <h5 style="color:#205ba0; margin-bottom:0px; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px;">Our Office</h5> Our office is located in the heart of Seven Sisters; an up and coming area in North London. Seven Sisters has had a lot of improvement in recent years with the Central & European investments into the area.<br> Seven Sisters have an excellent transport
    links. Commuters have the options of Victoria line to West End or British rail to Liverpool Street.<br><br>

    <h5 style="color:#205ba0; margin-bottom:0px; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px;">Contact</h5> Telephone: 020 8211 0005<br> Email: enquiries@abbapropertyservices.co.uk<br> Address: ABBA Property Services, 88 West Green Road, London N15 5NS<br><br>

    <h5 style="color:#205ba0; margin-bottom:0px; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px;">Transport</h5> Tube/Train: Seven Sisters Underground Station, Seven Sisters Railway Station, South Tottenham Railway Station<br> Bus: 41, N41<br><br>

    <h5 style="color:#205ba0; margin-bottom:0px; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px;">Opening Hours</h5> Monday: 9am - 5pm<br> Tuesday: 9am - 5pm<br> Wednesay: 9am - 5pm<br> Thursday: 9am - 5pm<br> Friday: 9am - 5pm<br> Saturday: 10am - 1pm<br> Sunday: Closed<br>
  </div>

  <div id="find-photo" class="col-md-5">
    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2479.0948652696484!2d-0.07885818431106212!3d51.584824712860375!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x48761c1135485d4b%3A0x487d1b5ae3bd4621!2s88+W+Green+Rd%2C+London+N15+5NS!5e0!3m2!1sen!2suk!4v1491925605605"
      width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You make it look easy! Thank you so very much!

Comment: Although this does cause problems with responsiveness.. do you has a possible solution that is also responsive?

Comment: @T.Doe what "responsive" behavior doesn't work or are you expecting?

Comment: Once the extra commands are added to the wrapper it causes excess overflow to the right and no longer becomes centred - this all occurs whilst displayed on a mobile screen.

Comment: You can center the contents with `justify-content: center` on `.wrapper` and if you want them to wrap onto new lines if there isn't enough horizontal space for them to display, add `flex-wrap: wrap`

Comment: @T.Doe here's a visual guide of the things you can do with flex https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @T.Doe my pleasure :)